# Generate uniformly random float which can return all possible values

Tags: go, random, floating-point

An easy way to generate a random float64 in [0,1) is by generating a uniformly random int in [0,2⁵³) and dividing it by 2⁵³. This is essentially what [`rand.Float64()`](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go?s=5359:5391#L168) is doing.
However, not all possible float64 values between 0 and 1 can be generated this way: if the value is lower than 2⁻⁴ for example, the 4 last bits of the significand are always going to be 0. Or, put more simply, the naive method always returns multiples of 2⁻⁵³, and not all floating point numbers between 0 and 1 are multiples of 2⁻⁵³.

How do you generate a uniformly random float64 such as every possible value has a chance of being returned? (Here, uniformly random means over the *real interval* [0,1): conceptually, I want to pick a uniformly random real number between 0 and 1 and return the closest float.)

For context, I need this because I'm implementing [this paper](https://crysp.uwaterloo.ca/courses/pet/F18/cache/Mironov.pdf) and the assumption "all possible values between 0 and 1 are represented" is essential for the result to hold.

Comment: `rand.Float64()` is probably the closest in-built way of doing it https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand.Float64

Comment: No, `rand.Float64()` does it the naive way and doesn't return every possible value. I edited the question to add a link.

Comment: with the chance of getting 1 being 1/2⁵³ i don't think you need to worry about it, if you do worry about it the docs you linked under cincenzo's answer explain how to fix it. so you can implement rand float 64 yourself

Comment: You probably have to implement this yourself. https://mumble.net/~campbell/2014/04/28/ might be a starting point.

Comment: Are you sure the paper you posted is correct? I don't understand the math but your quoted sentence is not in there. Besides, edit the question afterwards changing the topic is not the more polite (or correct) thing to do.

Comment: The paper denotes D the set of real numbers representable as float64, and much of the reasoning is based on this assumption (ctrl+f "their ulps vary between"). I think the paper is correct, although I haven't checked every calculation.

Comment: _" if the value is lower than 2⁻⁴ for example, the 4 last bits of the significand are always going to be 0"_ Where are you getting this from?

Comment: @icza If the exponent is -4 (or less), the last 4 bits of the significant correspond to precision strictly lower than 2⁻⁵³, and you're only generating multiples of 2⁻⁵³.

Comment: The paper tells you what to generate: “A uniform distribution over D ∩ (0, 1) can be generated by independently sampling an exponent (from the geometric distribution with parameter .5) and a significand (by drawing a uniform string from {0, 1}⁵²).” That omits discussion of subnormals. I suspect covering the normals suffices for their purposes, but completing the geometric distribution by duplicating the probability for the least normal exponent and the subnormal values would fit nicely. (The probability of each floating-point number in [0, 1) would be proportional to its ULP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porting [this code](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/random_real.c) (suggested in Severin's answer) is a possible option.

I think that it is equivalent to first generate the significand bits (by generating a random float in [1,2)), and then choose the exponent from a geometric distribution (it has a 0.5 chance of being -1, 0.25 of being -2, etc.).

```
// uniform returns a uniformly random float in [0,1).
func uniform() float64 {
  sig := rand.Uint64() % (1 << 52)
  return (1 + float64(sig)/(1<<52)) / math.Pow(2, geometric())
}

// geometric returns a number picked from a geometric
// distribution of parameter 0.5.
func geometric() float64 {
  b := 1
  for rand.Uint64()%2 == 0 {
     b++
  }
  return float64(b)
}
```

We can probably make geometric() faster by using one of the `LeadingZeros*` functions from the [`bits`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits/#LeadingZeros) package instead of doing one coin flip per bit.

Comment: If you're going to port code directly, things would depend on ldexp() implementation. I quickly looked through Go runtime and glibc implementation, and there are quite some differences to my surprise.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm taking another approach for the implementation. I think both are conceptually equivalent (but would be happy to be proven wrong).

Answer (score 2):

Well, standard way, I believe, is to generate up to 1074bits integer and map it to the double. Beware, that your RNG should have internal state at least 1074bits long.

Reference implementation: http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/random_real.c

Discussion about it: http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/

Another good link: https://lemire.me/blog/2017/02/28/how-many-floating-point-numbers-are-in-the-interval-01/

Comment: (a) That is a way, not “the standard” way. (b) Its range is [0, 1], but the question asks for [0, 1). It does mention the range can be reduced by rejection sampling (retry if the result is 1). (c) It generates 1074 only conceptually; in practice it uses many smaller bits in almost all cases.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `(a)` Doesn't seems to be a better way. `(b)` yep, rejection comes to rescue, I believe it is mention in comments. `(c)` yes, thank you, I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because the binary64 floating point numbers are not uniformly spaced, you cannot generate a uniform distribution which can return all possible values less that 1.

If you omit the requirement *uniform* you have to generate all representable multiples of the smallest positive denormal number `2^(-1074)`and zero.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. Essentially, I want do as if I were selecting a real number uniformly randomly between 0 and 1 and rounding it to the next float. I think Severin's answer is what I'm looking for. I'll implement it in Go.

Comment: You should add this to your question, but be aware that your mapping can generate 1 for values in the interval (1-2^(-53), 1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use brute-force rejection sampling by generating 16 random bytes and using it only if it's a valid float64 in `[0,1)`. This approach should give you a uniform distribution of all values in that range with performance not much worse than other strategies based on simple benchmarking.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/eP94aRi0zV4)):

```
import "math/rand"

func randFloat64() float64 {
  for {
    f := math.Float64frombits(rand.Uint64())
    if f >= 0 && f < 1.0 {
      return f
    }
  }
}
```

If performance is critical then you could build an enormous lookup table containing only the valid numbers and choose a random location in the table. The table could be generated ahead of time in a similar fashion as above, by enumerating the bitfield and storing only valid numbers.

Comment: Thanks — but this generates a uniform distribution over the possible elements, not over the real interval. I clarified the question.